# unlimited input javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a project where i have to put in multiple fields simply need to add a new field every time i press add new field on the page. i wrote this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 addNewLicns();
});



function addNewLicns () {
 var i = 1
 SecId = i + 3
 LicenseNumber         = "nptLicenseNumber"
 Province              = "nptProvince"
 LicenseCoun           = "nptLicenseCoun"
 licenseExpMonth       = "nptlicenseExpMonth"
 licenseExpDay         = "nptlicenseExpDay"
 licenseExpYear        = "nptlicenseExpYear"
 PhysicalExpMonth      = "nptPhysicalExpMonth"
 PhysicalExpDay        = "nptPhysicalExpDay"
 PhysicalExpYear       = "nptPhysicalExpYear"
 CurrentLicense        = "nptCurrentLicense"
 CommercialLicense     = "nptCommercialLicense"
 CommercialClass       = "nptCommercialClass"
 NoneEndorsements      = "nptNoneEndorsements"
 TankerEndorsements    = "nptTankerEndorsements"
 XEndorsements         = "nptXEndorsements"
 DoublesEndorsements   = "nptDoublesEndorsements"
 HazMatEndorsements    = "nptHazMatEndorsements"
 OtherEndorsements     = "nptOtherEndorsements"
 HaZmatExpMonth        = "nptHaZmatExpMonth"
 ZmatExpDay            = "nptZmatExpDay"
 ZmatExpDayExpYear     = "nptZmatExpDayExpYear";

    var htmlCont          = '<div class="NewLicnsHolder"> <div class="panel panel-default"> <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">License Information</h3><!-- /.panel-title --> </div><!-- /.panel-heading --> <div class="panel-body"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-4"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  LicenseNumber+i+'" class="control-label required-npt">License Number</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  LicenseNumber+i+'" name="'+LicenseNumber+i+'" maxlength="150" data-parsley-group="block5" aria-describedby="licenesnum" placeholder="Ex: 1234567 or A123456" required /> <span id="licenesnum" class="help-block">License format should be 7 numeric or 1 alpha + 6 numeric</span> </div><!-- /.col-md-4 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-4"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  Province+i+'" class="control-label required-npt">License State/Province</label> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  Province+i+'" id="'+Province+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value=""></option> <option value="AL">Alabama</option> <option value="AK">Alaska</option> <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> <option value="CA">California</option> <option value="CO">Colorado</option> <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> <option value="DE">Delaware</option> <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> <option value="FL">Florida</option> <option value="GA">Georgia</option> <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> <option value="ID">Idaho</option> <option value="IL">Illinois</option> <option value="IN">Indiana</option> <option value="IA">Iowa</option> <option value="KS">Kansas</option> <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> <option value="ME">Maine</option> <option value="MD">Maryland</option> <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> <option value="MI">Michigan</option> <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> <option value="MO">Missouri</option> <option value="MT">Montana</option> <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> <option value="NV">Nevada</option> <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> <option value="NY">New York</option> <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> <option value="OH">Ohio</option> <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> <option value="OR">Oregon</option> <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> <option value="TX">Texas</option> <option value="UT">Utah</option> <option value="VT">Vermont</option> <option value="VA">Virginia</option> <option value="WA">Washington</option> <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> <optgroup label="Provinces"> <option value="AB">Alberta</option> <option value="BC">British Columbia</option> <option value="MB">Manitoba</option> <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option> <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option> <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option> <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option> <option value="NU">Nunavut</option ><option value="ON">Ontario</option> <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option> <option value="QC">Quebec</option> <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option> <option value="YT">Yukon</option> </optgroup> </select> </div><!-- /.col-md-4 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-4"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  LicenseCoun+i+'" class="control-label required-npt">What vehicle class are you driving?</label> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  LicenseCoun+i+'" id="'+LicenseCoun+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="United States">United States</option> <option value="Canada">Canada</option> </select> </div><!-- /.col-md-4 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="required-npt col-md-12">License Expiration</div><!-- /.required-npt --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  licenseExpMonth+i+'" id="'+licenseExpMonth+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">MM</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  licenseExpDay+i+'" id="'+licenseExpDay+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">DD</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option> <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option> <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option> <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option> <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option> <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option> <option value="31">31</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <input type="text" class="form-control " id="';
        htmlCont         +=  licenseExpYear+i+'" name="'+licenseExpYear+i+'" maxlength="4" minlength="4" data-parsley-type="number" data-parsley-group="block5" placeholder="YYYY" required /> </div><!--/.pull-left --> </div><!-- /.input-group --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="required-npt col-md-12">Physical Expiration</div><!-- /.required-npt --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  PhysicalExpMonth+i+'" id="'+PhysicalExpMonth+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">MM</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  PhysicalExpDay+i+'" id="'+PhysicalExpDay+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">DD</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option> <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option> <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option> <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option> <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option> <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option> <option value="31">31</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <input type="text" class="form-control " id="';
        htmlCont         +=  PhysicalExpYear+i+'" name="'+PhysicalExpYear+i+'" maxlength="4" minlength="4" data-parsley-type="number" data-parsley-group="block5" placeholder="YYYY" required /> </div><!--/.pull-left --> </div><!-- /.input-group --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i+'" id="vldtion-label13" class="control-label required-npt">Is this your current driver license?</label> <span> <input type="radio" name="';
        htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i+'" id="'+CurrentLicense+i+'" data-parsley-class-handler="#vldtion-label13" value="Yes" data-parsley-group="block5" required> Yes <input type="radio" name="';
        htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i'" id="'+CurrentLicense+SecId+'" value="No"> No </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  CommercialLicense+i+'" id="vldtion-label14" class="control-label required-npt">Is this a commercial driver license?</label> <span> <input type="radio" name="';
        htmlCont         +=  CommercialLicense+i+'" id="'+CommercialLicense+i+'-nptshow" class="radio-holder" data-parsley-class-handler="#vldtion-label14" value="Yes" data-parsley-group="block5" required> Yes <input type="radio" name="';
        htmlCont         +=  CommercialLicense+i+'" id="'+CommercialLicense+i+'-npthidden" class="radio-holder" value="No"> No </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> <div class="col-md-2';
        htmlCont         +=  CommercialLicense+' npthidden"> <label for="'+CommercialClass+i+'" class="control-label">License Class</label> <select required name="';
        htmlCont         +=  CommercialClass+i+'" id="'+CommercialClass+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5"> <option value=""></option> <option value="Class A">Class A</option> <option value="Class AZ">Class AZ</option> <option value="Class B">Class B</option> <option value="Class C">Class C</option> <option value="Class D">Class D</option> <option value="Class E">Class E</option> <option value="Class 1">Class 1</option> <option value="Class 2">Class 2</option> <option value="Class 3">Class 3</option> <option value="Class 4">Class 4</option> <option value="Class 5">Class 5</option> </select> </div><!-- /.col-md-2 nptCommercialLicense npthidden --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';
        htmlCont         +=  NoneEndorsements+i+'" class="control-label">Endorsements</label> <span> <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  NoneEndorsements+i+'" name="'+NoneEndorsements+i+'" value="None">None <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  TankerEndorsements+i+'" name="'+TankerEndorsements+i+'" value="Tanker">Tanker <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  XEndorsements+i+'" name="'+XEndorsements+i+'" class="check-holder" value="X Endorsement">X Endorsement <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  DoublesEndorsements+i+'" name="'+DoublesEndorsements+i+'" value="Doubles / Triples">Doubles / Triples <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  HazMatEndorsements+i+'" name="'+HazMatEndorsements+i+'" class="ckeck-holder" value="Doubles / Triples">HazMat <input type="checkbox" id="';
        htmlCont         +=  OtherEndorsements+'" name="'+OtherEndorsements+'" value="Other">Other </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> <div class="nptHazMatEndorsements nptXEndorsements npthidden"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="required-npt col-md-12">Hazmat expiration date</div><!-- /.required-npt --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  HaZmatExpMonth+i+'" id="'+HaZmatExpMonth+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">MM</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <select name="';
        htmlCont         +=  ZmatExpDay+i+'" id="'+ZmatExpDay+i+'" class="form-control" data-parsley-group="block5" required> <option value="">DD</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <option value="11">11</option> <option value="12">12</option> <option value="13">13</option> <option value="14">14</option> <option value="15">15</option> <option value="16">16</option> <option value="17">17</option> <option value="18">18</option> <option value="19">19</option> <option value="20">20</option> <option value="21">21</option> <option value="22">22</option> <option value="23">23</option> <option value="24">24</option> <option value="25">25</option> <option value="26">26</option> <option value="27">27</option> <option value="28">28</option> <option value="29">29</option> <option value="30">30</option> <option value="31">31</option> </select> </div><!-- /.pull-left --> <div class="pull-left"> <input type="text" class="form-control " id="';
        htmlCont         +=  ZmatExpDayExpYear+i+'" name="'+ZmatExpDayExpYear+i+'" maxlength="4" minlength="4" data-parsley-type="number" data-parsley-group="block5" placeholder="YYYY" data-parsley-group="block5" required /> </div><!--/.pull-left --> </div><!-- /.input-group --> </div><!-- /.nptHazMatEndorsements nptXEndorsements npthidden --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> </div><!-- /.panel-body --> </div><!-- /.panel panel-default --> </div><!-- /.NewLicnsHolder -->'


 $('#addLicns').on('click', function() { 

        if(i >= 10) {
          alert("You can't add More than 10.");
        } else {
         $(".licnsContainer").append(htmlCont);


        }
        
        i++;
       

    });



      



}
```

to do this for me and it is giving me an issue right around line 47. i am not certain as i am a beginner in javascript if this is the best method or approach to this any advice will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: ...and which is line 47?

Comment: i apologize, it is this one   `      htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i'" id="'+CurrentLicense+SecId+'" value="No"> No </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';`

Comment: @SariYono can you mark answer below as accepted answer to question

Comment: @SariYono selecting answers give both you and Marcel points

Answer (score 2):

You missed concatenation (+) symbol at that line

What you write:

```
htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i'" id="'+CurrentLicense+SecId+'" value="No"> No </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';
```

What you should have written:

```
htmlCont         +=  CurrentLicense+i + '" id="'+CurrentLicense+SecId+'" value="No"> No </span> </div><!-- /.col-md-12 --> </div><!-- /.form-group --> <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-12"> <label for="';
```

Comment: thank you i really appreciate the help would you suggest a different approach to what i'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: you welcome! Different approach would be a template engine or reactjs

Comment: There's a lot of different approaches.  React might be best for non-beginners.  The easiest may be to embed a hidden div in your HTML, clone that with jQuery, then loop through and add/modify the attributes dynamically; which would be even easier if you leveraged the data attribute, so you could say `$('.template').clone().find('.update-attributes').each(function(){ var $t=$(this); $t.attr({'for': $t.data('for')+i || '', 'id': $t.data('id')+i || '' }); })`

Comment: @vol7ron +1 simple and efficent. Just like a simple template engine